# Bad option: ';_;' when building Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compilation, customization, jshint

I just installed and configured the environment to build customized versions of Twitter Bootstrap locally.

This what I did:

1. Install node
2. Install npm
3. Install less
4. clone Bootstrap locally
5. run `make build` to compile Bootstrap

**Step 5:**

```
~/devel/parking/bootstrap$ make build
jshint js/*.js --config js/.jshintrc

js/bootstrap-affix.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-alert.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-button.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-carousel.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-collapse.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-dropdown.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-modal.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-popover.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-tab.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-tooltip.js: line 24, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-transition.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.
js/bootstrap-typeahead.js: line 23, col 17, Bad option: ';_;'.

13 errors
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

**Line 23:**

```
"use strict"; // jshint ;_;
```

I was able to resolve the issue removing `// jshint ;_;` from line 23. Though, I'd prefer to leave Bootstrap sources untouched.

How can I get rid of those errors and what does the "Bad option" error mean?

---

**js/.jshintrc:**

```
{
    "validthis": true,
    "laxcomma" : true,
    "laxbreak" : true,
    "browser"  : true,
    "eqnull"   : true,
    "debug"    : true,
    "devel"    : true,
    "boss"     : true,
    "expr"     : true,
    "asi"      : true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same error just now, after searching the bootstrap issue,

I found the solution, please look at these:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/5244
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7043

Comment: Thanks. I used [the Makefile](https://raw.github.com/ahockersten/bootstrap/10e8efe3cfa1c839abe71bc0cd45076a095d2a09/Makefile) referenced in [this pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7022/files). I also changed the `BIN_PREFIX` value to reflect my path but the issue persists.

Comment: Can you put some of the details from that link in your answer? Link only answers aren't that useful if/when the link goes away.

Comment: I don't know why but seems it can't use the jshint installed globally. I use patch from this URL：https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/5344/files ，your link is for version 3.0。Just replace the Makefile in bootstrap folder， before make， don't forget to do 'npm install' to install the dependent locally， then make will succeeded.

Comment: If you are using the Bootstrap master branch, it's better to edit the Makefile manully, only need change three lines.

Comment: Should be fixed in 2.3.1: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/a61322c2fb55769cf89216879a17c1e924ca1be2

Comment: Both links are broken so this isn't an answer anymore

Answer (score 17):

The issue today is that JSHint's latest version is not compatible with the current Bootstrap Makefile because previous silent warnings now throw errors.

Remove JSHint `npm uninstall jshint` and then install version 0.9.1 `npm install jshint@0.9.1`. Finally run `make` and it compiles successfully.

Comment: You also need the correct version of uglify: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/cFy3J0nhfwM

Comment: npm install uglify-js@1

Answer (score 3):

Simply uninstalling JSHint didn't do it for me. Here's what I did following [this advice](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/twitter-bootstrap/cFy3J0nhfwM/65fEnkOTPGYJ).

```
cd bootstrap
npm uninstall -g uglify-js jshint recess connect
npm uninstall uglify-js jshint recess connect
npm install 
mkdir bin
cd bin
ln -s ../node_modules/*/bin/* . ; ln -s hint jshint
cd ..
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/bin
```

After that cleanup just run:

```
make
```

or any other make directive.

Comment: Thank you so much! Bootstrap 3 doesn't seem to have a makefile at all :(

Comment: Doing this, where are the final bootstrap files?, I mean the compiled files